# Negated OR vs. IN conditions in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Hi I have a table 'ABC' with primary key 'ID' which is a foreign key in table XYZ as 'ID'.

I am trying to delete from ABC depending on condition that ID!='A' or ID!='A2'. I have two queries.

`DELETE FROM ABC WHERE ID NOT IN ('A','A2')`

AND

`delete from ABC where ID !='A' or ID !='A2'`

I assume that both are same and correct logically. But I am getting integrity error for XYZ table in the second one where I am using 'OR' condition.

Could someone please help and tell why is it happening.

EDIT:: sorry that was by mistake

Comment: Not the same column , `team_tenant , id` , so , not (not necessarily) the same logic .

Comment: In the first query you are using the ID column and in the second one you are using ID and team_tenant column. They are not the same.

Comment: Sorry that was by mistake :)

Comment: The question is not Oracle specific. Any database that enforces referential integrity should behave the same (only the wording of the error message differs).

Comment: BTW: this condition: `ID !='A' or ID !='A2'` **is always true** and the optimizer simply skips it.. When `ID='A` then the first part of the condition `ID != 'A`' is false, but the second part `ID != 'A2`' is true, so the whole condition `part1 OR part2` is true. Likewise,, when `ID='A2'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two queries **are not** identical.

The first one keeps the entries having `ID` either `'A'` or `'A2'`. The second one deletes all the entries from the `ABC` table.

The condition:

```
ID IN ('A', 'A2')
```

is the same as:

```
ID = 'A' OR ID = 'A2'
```

Negating the condition:

```
ID NOT IN ('A', 'A2')
```

is the same as:

```
NOT (ID = 'A' OR ID = 'A2')
```

which, according to the [De Morgan laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is the same as:

```
NOT (ID = 'A') AND NOT (ID = 'A2')
```

which is the same as:

```
ID != 'A' AND ID != 'A2'
```

Your condition (`ID != 'A' OR ID != 'A2'`) removes the rows having `ID = 'A'` because they match the other half of the condition (`ID != 'A2'`). The same for the rows having `ID = 'A2'`.